# How to clear a HashArray in Poly/ML?

Tags: sml, polyml

Not much methods for that, I found only two methods about that? **delete, fold**.

so I do:

```
fold ( fn ( k, _, _ ) => delete ( h, k ) ) () h;
```

But I don't Think it is a good idea? How to do that smart?

Comment: There seems to be no other way, except maybe storing the `HashArray` itself in a `ref` and updating the `ref` with a brand new `HashArray` when you want to clear it. Depends on your constraints.

Comment: Thanks, I like it.